# Windows disk-folder sync utilities

Tags: windows-10, backup, sync

Using 2 external drives for backup and archiving. The 2nd drive needs to be a mirror copy of the first. Can anyone give their recommendation for  the best synchronizing tool? 
A quick google search gave me these free options
http://www.thewindowsclub.com/file-folder-synchronization-freeware

but am willing to pay if there is a better solution.

Comment: I use `rsync` for this - it's a very powerful tool with many options, but it's perfectly suited to this task. [Here](http://www.jveweb.net/en/archives/2010/11/synchronizing-folders-with-rsync.html) is a guide.

Answer (score 0):

ROBOCOPY works perfectly fine for me. Type "ROBOCOPY /?" in a CMD window and see all the options (it is a part of Windows!)

For example,

ROBOCOPY /E /Z /DCOPY:T /PURGE /FP "C:\Source" "D:\Target"

replaces everything in D:\Target with whatever is in C:\Source, doing all needed copying, removing, etc, in D:\Target. It is pretty fast when you only transfer delta changes.

For trying around, add /L at the end, that lists only what it *would do*, but doesn't actually *do* it.

Answer (score 0):

[Bvckup 2](https://www.bvckup2.com) is the best of the breed in mirroring software if you are open to paid options. If not, then built-in `robocopy /mt` is indeed a good option. FreeFileSync used to be another good option, but its author started bundling some banner/malware earlier this year, so *caveat emptor*.